# Does this class makes any sense to anyone

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I am a dirty c# programmer and today I am going through a senior developer's code, I realized they made every "thing" an object "a class" and followed patterns like "abstract factory" and created interfaces, abstract base classes etc
I am finding it bit hard to get it all in my mind to understand the code, and reasons behind relationship of abstracts and interfaces + factory.
I looked at videos and understand them individually but all together when I am trying to understand them in this scenario, it winds me up.

**Back to question (I changed objects names because of privacy)**

Here is the part of class I can't understand as what pattern or principals has been applied to it,

```
internal sealed class Mango : GenericMango, IMango
    {
        public static readonly IMangoFactory<IMango> Factory;

        static Mango()
        { // this line below specially i don't understand
            Factory = new MangoFactory<IMango>((aBC, disposeMango) => new Mango(aBC, disposeMango));
        }

        private Mango(string aBC, bool disposeMango)
            : base(aBC, disposeMango)
        {
        }

        // more methods and properties in here etc..
```

Comment: In which library can you find the Factory class ? It seems to be an IoC / Dependency Injection pattern.

Comment: The `eatableMango` bit is the most confusing bit. Try `edibleMango` instead, that should work!

Comment: Looks like `MagoFactory` takes in a `Func<string, bool>` which he is passing in as a lambda expression. If you're problem stems from what a lambda expression or delegates are, there are plenty of resources online to give you a starting point.

Comment: @musefan on your request I changed eatableMango to DisposeMango

Comment: `disposeMango`?!?! ....how cruel. A little fact about the word "mango" that not many people will tell you: it's not an anagram of "lemon"

Comment: I see some flaws in this code. If every type owns its `Factory` then no need of a factory at all. Factory is used to create different types of instances based on input. but this factory seems to create only `Mango`. Correct me if am wrong. [Factory Pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory).

Comment: Since the constructor is private, I'd expect to see a static method on the class that calls the factory method to create a new instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to help you, as I don't understand what you don't understand.

Of course, I don't know why the original developer went to this trouble and yet didn't go to the trouble of using dependency injection.

Zooming in specifically on your problem line:

```
Factory = new MangoFactory<IMango>((aBC, eatableMango) => new Mango(aBC, eatableMango));
```

I'm going to assume that you know what an anonymous delegate is, and what a lambda expression is.  If you aren't familiar with these, then Igor is your man for the answer.

This is basically the "lambda expression as factory method" subspecies of singleton factory pattern.

I'm also assuming that somewhere in MangoFactory there is a Func<string,bool,IMango> member.  This is the function used by the MangoFactory to generate new Mangos.

Ultimately, the pattern being followed is one where (likely) the following line is what it used to instantiate a Mango:

```
var theMango = Mango.Factory.CreateMango("foo",true);
```

And the goal was to hide the details of Mango construction.

Comment: I would assume this is the right answer, going to do more research now as I am not aware of delegates much

Answer (score 1):

```
Factory = new MangoFactory<IMango>((aBC, eatableMango) => new Mango(aBC, eatableMango));
```

It is using of lambda expression, syntax sugar for delegate

See the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx